# Convert Rows to Columns in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table like this :

```
MNUM   EXP_TYP   ExpenseLabel   AMOUNT
572711   2          Taxes        7080
572711   3          Insurance    3730
572711   4          Electric     7800
572711   5          WaterIncome  6000
572711   7          Trash        2400
572711   8          Gardner      1200
572711   14         AnnOperExp   900
572741   2          Taxes        8400
572741   3          Insurance    1200
572741   5          WaterIncome  4800
572741   7          Trash        1200
572741   8          Gardner      1800
572741   11         RepairMaint  1200
572741   34         Pest         80
```

I want the result like this :

```
MNUM    Taxes Insurance Electric WaterIncome Trash  AnnOperExp RepairMaint Pest
572711   7080   3730     7800       6000      2400     900
572741   8400   1200                4800      1200               1200       80
```

This is what I  tried :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ExpenseLabel) 
                    from #TempExpensesTab
                   group by MNUM,ExpenseLabel,EXP_TYP,AMOUNT
                    order by EXP_TYP
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select ExpenseLabel, AMOUNT
                from #TempExpensesTab
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(AMOUNT)
                for ExpenseLabel in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I am getting the following error :  "`The column 'Taxes ' was specified multiple times for 'p'.`"

Thanks

Comment: You already know about pivot so come on,why no tries..

Comment: This doesn't need unpivot or cross apply, this is a pivot, unless you aren't telling us everything.

Comment: Change this `group by MNUM,ExpenseLabel,EXP_TYP,AMOUNT` to `group by ExpenseLabel,EXP_TYP`. The problem is that you are getting multiple values for each column name because you are grouping by distinct values. You could see the incorrect columns by `print @cols` or `select @cols`.

Comment: thank u that worked.  How can i put that data into a temp table.?  The temp table is out of scope when used inside dynamic sql.